# matplotlib: How to plot_date without clipping NaN at the beginning and end

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have values (`np.array`) I want to plot against index (`DateTimeIndex`) with `ax.plot_date`. Both have the same length.

```
>>>index 
DatetimeIndex(['1997-12-30', '1997-12-31', '1998-01-01', '1998-01-02',
               '1998-01-05', '1998-01-06', '1998-01-07', '1998-01-08',
               '1998-01-09', '1998-01-12',
               ...
               '2015-12-29', '2015-12-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-01-01',
               '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07',
               '2016-01-08', '2016-01-11'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=4705, freq='B')

>>>values
array([        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  1.40211106,
    1.46409254,  1.36151557])
```

Now `ax.plot_date(index, values)` works fine except it will just clip the line at the beginning (the nan's) where I want to have the gap instead. I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't what do you want. Do you have an image? Also, having a working code would help to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the xtick labels manually, here's an example with only 4 items in the index, and 2 values in values:

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

#my made up data
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1997-12-30', '1997-12-31', '1998-01-01',
'1998-01-02'])
values = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 1.402, 1.464]) 

#we are actually using this array as the x values in our graph, then replacing the labels with dates
x = np.arange(len(index))

#create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0,len(index)])

#create axes with dates along the x axis
ax.set(xticks=x, xticklabels = index)

#plot values with the corresponding dates
ax.plot_date(x, values)

#show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Your example works fine. In my case it disables `ax.set_major_locator(YearLocator())` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y'))` methods though. The line in the plot is as it should be with the gaps, but with more than 10 years worth of data no dates are printed on the x-axis at all.

Comment: Found a solution: with `ax.set_xlim([index[0], index[-1]])` the `ax.set(xticks=x, xticklabels = index)`is not needed. I plot with `ax.plot_date(index, values)` and everything works as expected. Thanks again